# How can i make a lookup menu searchable?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-list

Situation:

I have a list and a library.

The list has a lookup column that allows you to choose multiple documents from the library.

Problem:

The library has several hundred documents, so it's very difficult to find the right document(s) to add to the list item.
Is there any way I can implement a search function above the list of documents so the list filters dynamically as I start typing the beginning of the document reference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread to yours for your reference: **[How do I create a Searchable Lookup Field in SharePoint Online?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/75400552-2d18-4cb0-bdbc-3da1ba47d7b3/how-do-i-create-a-searchable-lookup-field-in-sharepoint-online?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)**